# laravel enviroment when on command line different to in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my laravel app to an elastic beanstalk enviroment.  This app detects its environment with this piece of code in bootstrap/start.php

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

When elastic beanstalk starts it runs its configuration files which I have set up to detect if a parameter is set.  in this case I have set this parameter to development and the configuration files then set enviroment variables based on this namely

```
APP_ENV = development
DB_HOST = rds dev endpoint
DB_NAME = rds dev db name
DB_USERNAME = dev username
DB_PASSWORD = devdb pass
```

When I visit the app in the browser it is working as intended and it is correctly connecting to the dev db.

When I ssh into the server and try to run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get a pdo exception no such file or directory

when I run

```
php artisan env
```

local is returned even though the environment variable APP_ENV is defined.  I am doubly sure that this variable is defined because when laravel errors in the browser I can see the variable with the value development in the server/request data along with the other environment variables that are created on environment launch

what am I missing?

edited to include personalised solution based on antonios answer

.environment

```
<?php
if (getenv('PARAM1') === false) {
    return false;
} else {
    switch (getenv('PARAM1')) {
        case 'development':

            return array(
                'APP_ENV' => 'development',

                'DB_HOST' => '***',
                'DB_NAME' => '***',
                'DB_USERNAME' => '***',
                'DB_PASSWORD' => '***',
                );
            break;

        case 'staging':

            return array(
                'APP_ENV' => 'staging',

                'DB_HOST' => '***',
                'DB_NAME' => '***',
                'DB_USERNAME' => '***',
                'DB_PASSWORD' => '***',
                );
            break;

        case 'production':

            return array(
                'APP_ENV' => 'production',

                'DB_HOST' => '***',
                'DB_NAME' => '***',
                'DB_USERNAME' => '***',
                'DB_PASSWORD' => '***',
                );
            break;
    }
}
```

start.php

```
$env = require __DIR__.'/../.environment';

if ($env !== false) {
    foreach ($env as $key => $value) {
        putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value));
    }
}

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

Comment: Ok, but then, You get all your variables in your git???? I am exactly in the same case as you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
php artisan migrate
```

php runs under a different user, not your web server, so you need to:

```
php artisan migrate --env=development
```

**EDIT**

Having trouble with cli and web is one of the reasons why I don't use those web servers env vars. This is how I do my environments:

Create a .environment file in the root of your application and define your environment:

```
<?php

return array(

     'APP_ENV' => 'development',

     'POSTGRESQL.HOST' => 'localhost',
     'POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_NAME' => 'laraveldatabase',
     'POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_USER' => 'laraveluser',
     'POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_PASSWORD' => '!Bassw0rT',

);
```

Add it to your `.gitignore` application file, so you don't risk having your passwords sent to Github.

Right before `$app->detectEnvironment`, load the .environment file to PHP environment:

```
foreach(require __DIR__.'/../.environment' as $key => $value) 
{
    putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value));
}
```

And then you just have to use it:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    return getenv('APP_ENV');
});
```

It will work everywhere:

```
<?php

return array(

    'connections' => array(

         'postgresql' => array(
              'driver'   => 'pgsql',
              'host'     => getenv('POSTGRESQL.HOST'),
              'database' => getenv('POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_NAME'),
              'username' => getenv('POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_USER'),
              'password' => getenv('POSTGRESQL.DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
              'charset'  => 'utf8',
              'prefix'   => '',
              'schema'   => 'public',
         ),

    ),

);
```

Note that I don't do

```
return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
```

Because I want it to fail on every server I deploy my app to.

Comment: That makes sense, I just tried it though and got the same error.  Because its using a different user other than the web server should it have access to the environment variables it needs?  I just re-read my aws support case were I was given the method for setting the eniroment variables and he says 'One additional thing of note is that the custom environment variables set in this way will not be able to be modified via the Console.'

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try when I get a chance

Comment: Just getting around to trying this today and I have a question.  Do you create a different .enviroment file for each enviroment?  In git I have a master, staging and development enviroment.  If .enviroment is in the .gitignore file and I switch from say development to staging wont the .enviroment file remain unchanged with the development enviroment details?

Comment: Do you use all three environments in the same host? I create a .environment file in each folder/host. My development environment has one of those, which is completely different from the one I have on my production server, and if I have someone developing with me, in the same server, her .environment development file would be different from mine in some aspects, probably the database name would be different, but almost anything else could be the same, wouldn't conflict.

Comment: no not on the same host, elastic beanstalk spins up a different host for each environment but what enviroment spins up depends on what git branch I am in when I do 'eb start'. whatever the file contents in that branch are is what will be pushed to the enviroment so if the contents don't change from branch to branch then neither will the environment info being sent to the host.  I mightbe missing something and apologise if I am I only have a limited understanding of how this works

Comment: Well, if you have a host which can be in one environment or another, depending of the git branch you are when you start it, how can you tell (no PHP involved, because this is something to answer to solve a PHP problem) if this is a dev or production? A domain name (tld) or host pointing, the hostname...?

Comment: the elastic beanstalk command line tool takes care of that.  I have this question tagged with amazon web services and elastic beanstalk as well as laravel as I am not sure which technology provides the solution / causes the problem

Comment: I am going to try and set a single environment variable with the name of the environment on instance start and then add an if statement to your .environment file to check what that variable equals and then set the different settings according to that.  I think that should work

Comment: If it work, you can then have 3 different files and select the proper one by doing `require __DIR__.'/../.environment.'.getenv('YOURENVIRONMENTVARIABLE')`

Comment: I edited my question to include my version of your answer if you think there is a problem with anything I have done please let me know

Comment: I have excatly the same case, if .environment is in .gitignore, it will never be published by Elastic Beanstalk isn't it?