# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory when executing a command on Elastic Beanstalk / Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, env

I have a production app in Laravel 5.1 / AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

As I have several environment, and automatic deployment, I don't use .env, but I define my environment variables [directly on server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/envvar.html):

What happens is when the code is deployed to Elastic beanstalk, I can't execute no command because environment variables are not resolved.

So, when I execute:

```
 php artisan migrate
```

I get :

```
[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587320/laravel-enviroment-when-on-command-line-different-to-in-browser), user has the exact same issue as I have, but he resolves it making a .environment which contains vars for all his environments. I don't like it so much.

Then, if I put it in .gitignore, continuous deployment will never deploy it.

I don't know what to do, and wouldn't like to include my db connection settings in my git...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and solved it by adding the port to the end of the `DB_HOST`environment variable in Elastic Beanstalk. If someone has this problem and doesn't use EB env vars then try adding the port to the .env.

Answer (score -2):

The reason this message occurs is because PHP is looking for a MySQL socket file, and MySQL is not installed on the server, you'll need to use either RDS, or a MySQL instance hosted on EC2, or elsewhere.

To configure your database, you can either use the AWS EB command line tool, as documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html

e.g. `eb setenv DATABASE=laravel PASSWORD=123`

Or you can configure them using the web console:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/envvar.html

Saving these will cause the application to update, so do all of them at once, as you won't be able to edit anything while your change is deployed.

Other options include:

Store credentials in source control

Store them in the Elastic Beanstalk interface, which pushes them into the environment variables

Store them in a file on S3 which you lock down to be only accessible by your Elastic Beanstalk instances, add something to your .ebextensions configuration files

If you can clarify why any of these are not right, it might help find the correct solution.

Comment: I'm using RDS. It would be better to ask me instead of guessing

Comment: I didn't say you hadn't used RDS, I said that you will need to be using RDS or a separate EC2 instance, as this is intended to be an answer to help people having the same issue in the future.
Was this so unhelpful that it deserved a downvote? Didn't it provide a way to keep your configuration separate from your source code?

Comment: Thomas, I am grateful with anyone who try to help me, but I'm pretty sure your answer will not resolve my issue, and will not help neither. The downvote is an invitation to delete you answer and get your points back. This is how stackoverflow works. It allows to maintain quality in questions and answers.

Comment: If you don't want to use the mechanism provided by Elastic Beanstalk, what exactly are you looking for?
While you've called my answer low quality, you've still not in any way clarified what it is you *do* want.

Comment: I already use the elastic beanstalk environment variable, and that is the main issue, please refer to my question. And by the way, I didn't mean to hurt you, I just don't feel that you opened the links I provided

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood some of the question, and it's easy to get defensive when you've put energy into an answer and lose points.

Comment: how are you running your commands? Via ssh, in .ebextensions in a 'commands' directive, or 'container_commands'.
Also, are you using a regular PHP EB environment? Or a Docker based one. I use Docker + Nginx and PHP7 in EB, and my commands that use the database all run as 'container_commands'.

Comment: I run it as command. All php artisan commands fails, but specially, I need to execute php artisan backup:run from plugin: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup, then I will schedule those commands with Laravel 5

Comment: Try as a 'container_command', environment variables are only available from them, and not regular commands.

Comment: container_commands only run when code get deployed in server --> They run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed. They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS security credentials.

Comment: Yes, they do, only within a container_command and during the execution of the application via the web server are the only two places Amazon supports accessing the environment variables.
You said in a command, that's a special word, so you mean via SSH? Cron? Something else?

Comment: Yes, it is like a SSH Command, or cron, but managed internally by laravel . https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands - You end running in ssh something like : "php artisan command" where you coded "command". You can also schedule you command so it acts as a cron

Comment: I think is a Laravel artisan bug. I am having a similar issue on EB. I tested locally configuring connection variables on database.php using server variables and doesn't work but if I harcode these variables using "real" values, it works.